# Access Visual Studio DTE members specified in DTE2 interface in IronPython

Tags: ironpython, envdte

Using IronPython 3.4.0 I can get the visual studio's DTE object using:

```
import System

dteClassType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.16.0")
dte = System.Activator.CreateInstance(dteClassType)
```

In theory this object's type should implement [DTE2 Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.dte2?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) but I can't access its members.

I do have access to the members specified in the older [DTE interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)

Is there a way I can change the interface I am seeing? In C# it would be something like:

```
Type dteClassType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.16.0");
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Activator.CreateInstance(dteClassType);
```

But is this possible in Iron Python?

Tried from EnvDTE80 import DTE2
Tried clr.Convert()
Tried subclassing